# python sparse gmres messes with input arguments

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

I have a simple code to solve a sparse linear system using   scipy.sparse.linalg.gmres

```
W, S  = load_data()
M = normalize(W.T.astype('float64'),'l1')
S = normalize(S.astype('float64'),'l1')
rhs = S[cat_id,:].T
print M.shape
print rhs.shape 
p = gmres(M, rhs)
```

function load_data loads two sparse matrices from matlab's .mat files and omitted. 
The output is surprising:

```
(150495, 150495)
(150495, 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "explain.py", line 54, in <module>
    pr(1)
  File "explain.py", line 42, in pr
    p = gmres(M, rhs)
  File "<string>", line 2, in gmres
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/iterative.py", line 85, in non_reentrant
    return func(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/iterative.py", line 418, in gmres
    A,M,x,b,postprocess = make_system(A,M,x0,b,xtype)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/utils.py", line 78, in make_system
    raise ValueError('A and b have incompatible dimensions')
ValueError: A and b have incompatible dimensions
```

But I've run gmres in accordance with documentation

> A : {sparse matrix, dense matrix, LinearOperator}
>
> ```
> The real or complex N-by-N matrix of the linear system.
> ```
>
> b : {array, matrix}
>
> ```
> Right hand side of the linear system. Has shape (N,) or (N,1).
> ```

I simply don't understand what is wrong with this code and would like any ideas.

Comment: How do you get from the error message to the subject line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument `b` of [`gmres`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.gmres.html) must not be a sparse matrix; it can be a numpy array or matrix.  Try

```
p = gmres(M, rhs.A)
```